# Enter day tasks in Calendar without times

Tags: calendar, reminders

I feel constrained when I need to enter start and end time for a task because I know it can take another amount of time than entered.

Can I somehow just make a list of tasks for a day, one after another?
I saw all-day tasks, but I don't think these are what I need.

As an alternative, what tasks list could you recommend please?

Comment: Have you thought about Reminders?

Answer (score 2):

In Calendar, you can use the all-day events, that are shown one after the other.

Otherwise, you can choose among multiple apps. For free:

- There is the default app **Reminders**, that allows you to create lists of events that you can check once completed.
- One app I really like is **[Wunderlist](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wunderlist-to-do-list-tasks/id410628904?mt=12)**. It has a good layout. It does more or less the same as Reminders, but it has much more functionalities. Obviously, you can sync with other devices.
- You can also use **[Trello](https://trello.com)**, which is an app for mobile phones and you can use on your Mac through the website. I consider that Trello is very complete but a little trickier.

Of course there are much more apps. It depends to your personal taste. *De gustibus*...